# I want to get previous line to a matching string using Regex

Tags: regex, line

I am trying to get previous line to a matching string.

```
3465.09
3465.09
45431.00
Total Invoice Value( In Words): Rupees Forty Five Thousand Four Hundred Thirty One Only.
```

** I want to get "45431.00" based on next line "Total Invoice Value..........."  I tried with \n(.*)\n(.*)Total Invoice but i am getting the result as

Result:

```
45431.00
Total Invoice
```

I want only 45431.00

Comment: What are you using? Some programming language, command line? Also what is it the solution that you have tried so far?

Comment: Maybe: `.*(?=\s*\nTotal Invoice)`

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this regex will match any integer and float :

```
/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\nTotal Invoice/
```

Comment: You are assuming, without saying so, that it should return the string representation of an integer or float. Without a statement in the question that it could be an integer, and the example showing only floats, your assumption is questionable. At minimum, you should state your assumption.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this (written in Python)

```
text = """3465.09
3465.09
45431.00
Total Invoice Value( In Words): Rupees Forty Five Thousand Four Hundred Thirty One Only."""
re.findall(r'([\.\d]+)(?=\n[a-zA-Z])',text)
```

**output**

```
['45431.00']
```

or

```
re.search(r'([\.\d]+)(?=\n[a-zA-Z])',text).group(1)
```

**Output**

```
'45431.00'
```